# Perfectly center absolute positioned items regardless of font size

Tags: html, css

I want to vertically center my navigation items (li) with exactly half the text on the white part and the other half on the off-white part.

I've tried using "top: -0.83rem;" but I'm not sure if it's perfectly centered since I eyeballed it.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}

.section-border {
  border: 30px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: #f8f7f3;
}

.section-wrap {
  min-height: 600px;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.83rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 920px;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .home-link {
    flex-grow: 0;
  }
  li {
    text-align: right;
    flex-grow: 1;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .menu {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section-border">
  <div class="section-wrap">
    <header class="header">
      <nav role="navigation">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="home-link">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://www.nicolefenton.com/_/images/dec/circle-menu.svg" height="12" width="12" alt=""></a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Writing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Speaking</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want all five navigation items to be perfectly vertically centered regardless of font size. 1/2 of the item should be on the white part and 1/2 should be on the off-white part.

Comment: You want to center the `.menu` vertically within the `header` ?

Comment: That's already the case; if you increase the font size of the menu it's they'll still stay perfectly vertically-aligned.

Comment: Hi Zohir, I believe so. Whatever will make the top half of the text be inside the white border and bottom half of the text be inside the off-white color (#f8f7f3).

Comment: Are you sure it's vertically not horizontally ?

Comment: Yes, vertically centered, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Obsidian Age, if you zoom in, you can see that it is not perfectly centered. I was wondering if there was any way to make sure it is (calc function, perhaps?)

Comment: Those `li` elements are perfectly centered within the `.menu` element. i'm not sure what you talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this, I've changed the .menu and li styles:

```css
*, *:before, *:after { 
        box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;
        border: none; 
      }

      .section-border {
        border: 30px solid #ffffff;
        background-color: #f8f7f3;
      }

      .section-wrap {
        min-height: 600px;
      }

      .header {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 1rem;
        margin-right: 1rem; 
      }

      .menu {
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 920px;
        line-height: 1.5em;
      }

      li {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-size: 11px;
      }


      @media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
        .home-link {
          flex-grow: 0;
        }

        li {
          text-align: right;
          flex-grow: 1;
          font-size: 16px;
        }

        .menu {
          display: flex;
          flex: 1;
        }
      }
```

```html
<div class="section-border">
    <div class="section-wrap">
      <header class="header">
        <nav role="navigation">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li class="home-link"><a href="#"><img src="https://www.nicolefenton.com/_/images/dec/circle-menu.svg" height="12" width="12" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">test<br>test</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Writing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Speaking</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve horizontal and vertical centring of a child relative to a parent element via `absolute` positioning is via the use of the `transform` property:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  background: yellow;
  
  /* Translate the center element in top-left
  direction relative to its own dimensions to
  achieve center placement relative to parent */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* Not needed - resets the list to prevent non-centered appearance */
ul, li {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="center">
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here the top-left of `.center` is placed at the centre of `.wrapper`. We use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` to then offset placement of `.center` relative to it's own dimensions, meaning that it's centre is shifted to the centre of `.wrapper`.

Note that the percentages of `translate` are relative to the dimensions of the `.center` element, meaning that regardless of the lists dynamic width/height, the `.center` will always be positioned in the middle of `.wrapper`